# a question about my rsync script

Tags: server, bash, backup, rsync

So I've recently written a bash script for rsync, to sync an usb hard drive to a folder on my server. A day or two after running the script I notice some files are missing from the source folder.

Could someone be a darling and check my script to see if it would have deleted files from the source? (server folder) or if it is just deleting files from the destination (usb hdd) that are no longer on the source (as I meant for it to do).

```
 #!/bin/bash
# rsync folders

SOURCEDIR=/raid/orm_data/outputBatch2/rsta
DESTDIR=/media/exthdd/batch2

cd $SOURCEDIR
sudo rsync -h -v -r -P -t --delete-after --exclude="*/*/*/THUM" --exclude="*result*" --exclude=".DS_Store" --exclude="._.DS_Store" --include="*.pdf" --include="*.PDF" --include="*.jpg" --include="*.JPG" --include="*.tif" --include="*.TIF" --include="*.xhtml" --include="*.XHTML" --include="*.xml" --include="*.XML" $SOURCEDIR $DESTDIR
```

Hopefully it wasn't down to the script (I mean it worked in testing).
Any help would be awesome =]
Pleases and thank yous!

Comment: What files are missing?

Comment: Some .tif and .pdf files are missing from the server/source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only `rsync` option you have used that can potentially remove file is `--delete-after` but that deletes files from the destination, not from the source. This is true for all `--delete` options of `rsync`. The only option to remove files from source is `--remove-source-files`.

So your `rsync` command should not remove any file from source.

On a different note, the `-h` option is for help, which is doing nothing in your case, also you should look at the `-a` (`--archive`) option as you are already using most of the options it includes.

Also as you have many `--include` patterns, you should rather define the patterns in a file and use `--include-from` option instead to make the command line more readable and easily maintainable.

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge =] much appreciated (sorry about the late response :/    )